# adb return "device not found" GLX T1 kitkat android tablet on fedora

Tags: android, adb, fedora

I have problem connecting my new tablet using adb. The development os is Fedora. I have also checked the device in Windows 7 with same result. The device is detected as "android" and windows is unable to find the driver for it.

There is no driver available in official site too. I know how to connect a device in debug mode and don't have problem with my other devices. I just have problem on connecting this to adb.

Information according to CPU-Z app:

CPU : ARM Cortex-a7

Platform: sun8i

CPU: 1.54GHz

Board: GLX

GPU Renderer Mali-400 MP

Display: polaris-g739_wifibt_hd_4.4v1.0_2.5_0.3_20140711

android version: 4.4.2

kernel version 3.4.39(20140711)

Total Ram: 905 MB

UPDATE:

lsusb command return:

Bus 001 Device 025: ID 1f3a:1002 Onda (unverified)

UPDATE:
i am in root already,
using this command with no success:

adb kill-server

adb start-server

adb devices return : 
List of devices attached

Comment: yes, i did all of them , and when connect usb, show usb debugging enabled on notification

Comment: My previous comment was stupid. I should've read through completely. My apologies. Is the **USB mass storage** option on? That could be a culprit. I know on Android 4.2.x devices both adb and usb storage cannot be used simultaneously but in a Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.x I have seen both options work simultaneously.

Comment: no, usb mass storage is off in device

Comment: Is your android-51.rules file configured correctly?

Comment: 3mpty, there is no /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules file, i use official portable version of eclipse, not using installed version on using yum

Comment: This link will help you setup your rules file : http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Android_Applications_on_a_Physical_Kindle_Fire_Device

Comment: thanks, linux adb configuration(in that link work great(http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Android_Applications_on_a_Physical_Kindle_Fire_Device#Linux_Kindle_Fire_adb_Configuration)

Comment: Am glad it worked for you. Please accept the answer so this thread can be closed. Oh and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing **/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules** is the reason for the issue faced at hand. Creating this file and re-configuring adb will allow connection to the device at hand.

This [Adb configuration guide](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Android_Applications_on_a_Physical_Kindle_Fire_Device#Linux_Kindle_Fire_adb_Configuration) will take you a long way in accomplishing this.

That said, I suggest you keep an eye on your system and the updates it receives. A missing **51-android.rules** file in a configured development machine is no coincidence.

Answer (score -1):

W7 64
After working for 3 hrs for a solution, simply: 
Take a look at the Windows Hardware Manager: It showed up that the ADB driver wasn't installed; Nevertheless it's an unsigned driver, accepted and is working as expected ...

Comment: This is about Linux (Fedora), not Windows

Comment: Sry, take a look at the top => cite: I have also checked the device in Windows 7 with same result.